# Can't multiple insert using openrowset

Tags: sql, sql-server, openrowset

I already searched a couple of times. Some post are related but still can't help me on this problem.

Here are the sample items of my items.txt. I checked the .txt file and there is absolutely no white space, etc.

```
0000100000
7005432111
4545213695
4545213612
0000100001
0000100002
```

So here's my code so far:

```
INSERT INTO items(id, customerID)
SELECT items.id , C.customerID
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\items.txt', FORMATFILE='C:\items.fmt') AS items
    LEFT JOIN customerTable AS C ON items.id = C.id
```

And it returns this values:

```
0000100000  NULL
7005432111  NULL
4545213695  NULL
4545213612  NULL
0000100001  NULL
0000100002  NULL
```

It return NULL values in the customerID column, wherein there should be some data there. I think the problem is on `items.id = C.id` it cannot read each values from items.txt but when I use this code:

```
INSERT INTO items(id, customerID)
SELECT items.id , C.customerID
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\items.txt', FORMATFILE='C:\items.fmt') AS items
    LEFT JOIN customerTable AS C ON C.id = '0000100000'
```

It returns this:

```
0000100000  2
7005432111  2
4545213695  2
4545213612  2
0000100001  2
0000100002  2
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
The solution to the problem lies in the format file "items.fmt" (credits to @serverSentinel) Use \r\n to terminate the line.

```
10.0
1
1       SQLCHAR             0       46      "\r\n"     1     loyaltyID                    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: Can you add sample data of `customerTable`

Comment: Aparently, my VM just hanged so I can't check. But here are some chosen data:

`customerID, customerName, id`
`2                , Paulo,               , 0000100000`

Comment: Do you have any leading empty space in your `items.txt` file

Comment: leading empty space? the whole content of items.txt is as shown in the post. I will post the items.fmt.

Comment: ya i can see in sample data but not the text file. Make sure in text file before very item there no empty space

Comment: My VMis not responding. I'm very sorry. I'll check those empty space when it returns. But what might be the problem other than that empty spaces? it inserts the items.txt correctly, but not the customerID column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make absolutely sure of:

1) the items.txt is in UNIX line endings (\n) not Windows (\r\n).  This is most likely your problem.

Try this format to verify or use a text editor that can set the line mode

```
10.0
1
1       SQLCHAR             0       46      "\r\n"     1     loyaltyID                    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

2) The loyaltyID column is being read in as a char(46) SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. Check the data types for length, and definition. You may be having difficulties comparing an integer field to a char field.  cast appropriately. Less likely, check ansi_padding setting to make sure your varchar to char comparisons aren't comparing extra spaces.  Check your collations.  for example SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS is much different than latin1_general_bin.

If this doesn't solve your question, please post the schema for customerTable and some sample records.

Comment: I tried updating the columns but it doesn't work also. But when I changed my format terminator with `\r\n` it works!!! Awesome. Gonna check my other problems. I'm gonna mark this as answer later if there is no more errors/bugs. Thank you so much @serverSentinel

Answer (score 0):

```
My Text File Data(Store ProcessId) :-

21
22
23
24


 CREATE TABLE temp ( ProcessId VARCHAR(2000) ) ;
 BULK INSERT dbo.temp
    FROM 'D:\items.txt'
    WITH
    (
      CODEPAGE = '1252',
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
      CHECK_CONSTRAINTS
    ) 
 SELECT *
 FROM   temp
        INNER JOIN dbo.Process_Master ON Process_Id = ProcessId
```

Comment: I tried using bulk insert but `openrowset bulk` is more flexible. And how does this help me? Thanks

Comment: its easy to read file and  store data in temp table so u can easy work on table like join and condition etc.

Comment: yeah but my problem exactly is the join not working. As you can see on my code above, it seems that i can't get the `items.id` value properly. So what I think is a possible solution is to make a loop?